# SIGTSTP signal not stopping child?

Tags: c++, signals, fork, exec

I'm trying to write a program that forks, the child executes a command and then returns control to the parent. I am having trouble getting the SIGTSTP (C-z) signal to work as intended, though... I want the parent to ignore it, but the child to stop and return control to the parent, so that the child can later be resumed or killed (with a builtin command). I isolated the relevant code into a smaller program just to test it, and it seems like A) the child doesn't stop when C-z is typed, or B) it does stop, but does not return control to the parent (I'm leaning towards this because when I use cat for stdin, it behaves differently after the C-z). Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <signal.h>


int main(){
  std::cout.setf(std::ios::unitbuf);

  std::vector<std::string> vec; vec.push_back("cat");
  std::vector<char*> chvec;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
    chvec.push_back(&vec[i][0]);
  }
  chvec.push_back(NULL);
  vec.erase(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + chvec.size());

  char** argv = &chvec[0];
  signal(SIGTSTP,SIG_IGN);

  pid_t pid;
  if((pid = fork()) == 0){
    signal(SIGTSTP,SIG_DFL);
    /*pid = getpid();
    setpgid(pid,pid);*/
    std::cout << "before exec" << std::endl;
    execvp(argv[0],argv);
    perror("exec");
  }
  else{
    //setpgid(pid,pid);
    int status;
    waitpid(pid,&status,0);
    if(WIFEXITED(status) || WIFSIGNALED(status)){
      std::cout << "exited or signaled" << std::endl;
    }
    if(WIFSTOPPED(status)){
      std::cout << "process stopped" << std::endl;
    }
    //std::cout << "process exited" << std::endl;
    pause();
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `chvec[]` needs a trailing null pointer.

Comment: fixed that (though it doesn't seem to affect anything)

Comment: You can tell the difference between `A` and `B` by using `ps` in another terminal window. If the child is stopped it will be in `T` state.

Comment: I get a segmentation violation when I try to run your program. I think the problem is that you're erasing everything in `vec`. But `chvec` contains pointers to those strings.

Comment: Urgh..when I use ps in another window it doesn't even have my program on the list, just bash and ps. And that's weird, mine doesn't give a seg fault and runs commands fine (I've tried ls which ran fine), though what you're saying makes sense. The erasing isn't necessary in this small program, though it is something I need for the bigger program I'm making.

Comment: By default `ps` only shows processes running in the current terminal, use `ps x` to see processes from another terminal. I took out the `erase` and it ran without error, and I saw that the `cat` process is stopped.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks! I hadn't used the ps command before so I had no idea. I still wonder why I'm not getting the segmentation violation and you are? Could it have anything to do with compilation flags?

Comment: It's undefined behavior, anything can happen, including no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was already pointed out in the comments that you need to fix the undefined behavior as a result of the `vec` vector being erased. That's the first problem.

I see that your code is checking the exit status of a process using `WIFSTOPPED`.

Let's [review the documentation for the `wait(2)` system call](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/wait.2.html), and see what it says about this:

> ```
>   WIFSTOPPED(wstatus)
>          returns true if the child process was stopped by delivery  of  a
>          signal;  this  is  possible only if the call was done using WUN‐
>          TRACED or when the child is being traced (see ptrace(2)).
> ```

So, with that information at hand, after fixing the previously mentioned undefined behavior, and after changing your `waitpid()` call to:

```
waitpid(pid,&status,WUNTRACED);
```

Then I was able to send a `kill -TSTP <pid>` message to the spawned `cat` process, and obtain the expected

> process stopped

message from your test program.

P.S. By stracing the child process, I could see that the child process was receiving the `TSTP` signal, and stopping just fine. The issue was simply that the parent wasn't handling it, without the required option to `waitpid()`.

Comment: Oh my gosh...I actually tried using WUNTRACED before, but instead of waiting for a stop signal, cat stopped automatically for some reason (instead of waiting for C-z). I may have had some residual code from the many other things I tried that was messing stuff up, but this works now...thank you sooo much!